# How to track GCM Problems?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem I`m just not getting any GCM Messages. I dont want Pop Ups or sounds playing, it doesnt even fire the *onReceive()* Method in the Broadcast Reciever, which is, to my understanding, the first point the Application handles a message.

My biggest problem is I dont get any error messages or Hints. When I send a message, I get the message ID, a multicast ID and a "success=1" message. I also get a "Device registrated on any device and a Reg ID, a "already registered" running the app a second time. The Devices are also logged into Google Play, same account as on the Google API Console. But nothing happens on the Device when I send a GCM Message.

I post my complete android manifest, please let me know if you need more code. This is driving my crazy.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lottoapplicationandroid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:installLocation="auto"
 >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<permission android:name="com.lottoapplicationandroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"     android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.lottoapplicationandroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- ZXing activities -->
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" android:label="@string/share_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>


<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
 <category android:name="com.lottoapplicationandroid" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

</application>
```

**EDIT**

I dont need a solution for this if not possible. I´d be very thankful for hints how to find out what`s going wrong. E.g. I found out I have to have an open Port 5228. Does anybody know how to check if the devices is listening on that port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Issue is solved.

I had to turn Wi-Fi off.

> WiFi   /  Telephone-Network
>
> off   /   off   :                  not working
>
> on    /   off   :                  not working
>
> on    /   on     : not working
>
> off   /   on     :                 working

Comment: I dont know mate I think basically they do, the problem in our company is the firewall. I should have mentioned that. I can´t tell anymore specific without disturbing the sys-admin.

Comment: Hey, I'm in the same boat!  I have a WiFi-only tablet which wasn't getting notifications.  Connected through my phone's hotspot (via 3G), and notifications came flooding in.  Turns out our firewall allows Apple notifications through (port 5223), but not Android (5228-5230). I've asked nicely to change this, but...

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing some intent filters for the receiver ?

```
 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <category android:name="com.lottoapplicationandroid" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
          <category android:name="com.lottoapplicationandroid" />
      </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: hmm that was because the code in the textfield wasnt drawn in to the right. So it didnt show it, sorry!!! I have it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />     

   <receiver
                    android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
                    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                        <category android:name="packagename" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>

      <service android:name="Packagename.MyIntentService" >
            </service>


Try it hope so it works.
```