# GcmBroadcastReceiver does not receive any notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

**Kindly read last EDIT note, the issue is resolved.**

I have set up the GCM with code as directed in GCM official documentation.

I am able to 
1. Register the devices and receive the registrationIDs.
2. Have created the API project and able to send the message from Server with result success as -

```
{"multicast_id":7210001445807628862,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1392631541038778%b06e6126f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1392631541037185%b06e6126f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

3. **But, notification is not received!!**

I searched a lot but I do not have a clue what could be wrong !! Kindly help !!

Following is the code

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.techlovejump.gcm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.techlovejump.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.techlovejump.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.techlovejump.gcm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.techlovejump.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.techlovejump.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.techlovejump.gcm.GcmIntentService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.techlovejump.gcm.ReceiveActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_receive" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package com.techlovejump.gcm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This issue is **NOT** related to code.

As discovered and answered by Dan on link
[How to track GCM Problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293911/how-to-track-gcm-problems)

I had to turnoff WiFi and use telephone-mobile network to get notifications.
I am not sure why it is not working on Wifi; but that is the case for me...

Thanks

Comment: Are u sure the onReceive method is not getting called.. or the service is not started.

Comment: @lintu Your question is valid. I am not 100% sure. Is there a way to check this ?. I have started the app in debug mode with breakpoint within onReceive. But that is never invoked. I have high speed net connected to the android device. So I concluded that onReceive is not working.